# Reduce overlapping date ranges in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dilema in creating Oracle SQL statement for the following requirements:

Let's say I have these records in PROD_TABLE.

**PROD_TABLE**

| Assignment ID | Effective Start Date | Effective End Date | Action Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1/1/2010 | 2/2/2015 | Name Change |
| 1001 | 2/3/2015 | 5/5/2021 | Name Change |
| 1001 | 5/6/2021 | 3/3/2023 | Name Change |
| 1001 | 3/4/2023 | 12/31/4712 | Name Change |

And let's say I have these records in STAGING_TABLE.

**STAGING_TABLE**

| Assignment ID | Effective Start Date | Effective End Date | Action Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2/3/2015 | 5/5/2021 | Dept Change |
| 1001 | 5/6/2021 | 12/31/4712 | Manager Change |

**LOGIC WILL THE FOLLOWING...**
These records will stay the same. Only the ACTION_REASON field will be updated (based on the updates on STAGING_TABLE.ACTION_REASON field).

| Assignment ID | Effective Start Date | Effective End Date | Action Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1/1/2010 | 2/2/2015 | Name Change |
| 1001 | 2/3/2015 | 5/5/2021 | Dept Change |

These records from the PROD_TABLE will be removed because the date ranges overlaps in the STAGING_TABLE.

| Assignment ID | Effective Start Date | Effective End Date | Action Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5/6/2021 | 3/3/2023 | Name Change |
| 1001 | 3/4/2023 | 12/31/4712 | Name Change |

The overlapping date ranges will be changed depending on what will be the date range in the STAGING_TABLE.

| Assignment ID | Effective Start Date | Effective End Date | Action Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5/6/2021 | 12/31/4712 | Manager Change |

So, the expected output will be:
**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

| Assignment ID | Effective Start Date | Effective End Date | Action Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1/1/2010 | 2/2/2015 | Name Change |
| 1001 | 2/3/2015 | 5/5/2021 | Dept Change |
| 1001 | 5/6/2021 | 12/31/4712 | Manager Change |

```sql
CREATE TABLE PROD_TABLE(Assignment_ID   number, Effective_START_Date date,  Effective_END_Date date, ACTION_REASON VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('1/1/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Name Change');
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/3/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('5/5/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Name Change');
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('5/6/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('3/3/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Name Change');
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('3/4/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Name Change');

CREATE TABLE STAGING_TABLE(Assignment_ID    number, Effective_START_Date date,  Effective_END_Date date, ACTION_REASON VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE VALUES (30001,    TO_DATE('5/6/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Manager Change');
```

For now I have this SQL that cannot pull the correct results :(

```sql
WITH query1 AS (
    SELECT staging_table.assignment_id,
           GREATEST(staging_table.effective_start_date, prod_table.effective_start_date) AS effective_START_date,
           LEAST(staging_table.effective_end_date, prod_table.effective_end_date) AS effective_END_date,
           staging_table.ACTION_REASON
      FROM PROD_TABLE prod_table
      JOIN STAGING_TABLE staging_table
        ON prod_table.Assignment_ID = staging_table.Assignment_ID
     WHERE prod_table.effective_start_date < staging_table.effective_end_date
       AND prod_table.effective_end_date > staging_table.effective_start_date
),  
query2 AS (   
    SELECT * 
      FROM query1
     UNION
    SELECT prod_table.Assignment_ID,
           prod_table.effective_start_date,
           prod_table.effective_end_date,
           prod_table.ACTION_REASON
      FROM STAGING_TABLE prod_table
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM query1 qry
                        WHERE prod_table.Assignment_ID = qry.Assignment_ID
                          AND prod_table.effective_start_date BETWEEN qry.effective_start_date AND qry.effective_end_date)
)
SELECT qry.* 
  FROM query2 qry;
```

Comment: Did you mean to leave a 2-year gap? The second staging row starts in 2023, but seems to have replaced data starting in 2021. That may be a typo in your sample data... If it is, will the dates in the staging table really always align exactly with the existing rows in the prod table, or could you actually have gaps/overlaps/clashes between them - and how would those need to be resolved? (Also are you sure you want to replace the existing reason, rather than say concatenating them (e.g. to `'Name Change, Dept Change'` - not that I would advocate storing multiple values in one column of course.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it's a typo. it should 2021. the ACTION_REASON should be updated. what is in the STAGING_TABLE should be the updated value.

Comment: OK, and the gaps/overlaps question? Your query attempt is using <= and >= which suggests partial overlaps. What would happen, for instance, if that staging row started on 1/1/2021 or 1/1/2022 instead of 5/6/2021? You've shown one fairly straightforward scenario where everything lines up, but there could be a lot of complications and edge cases where the behaviour needs to be defined.

Comment: Hi, that is the only scenario I want for now. How to query those results is way very difficult for me :(

Answer (score 0):

> that is the only scenario I want for now

For the data you've shown with exact date matches, you can use an outer join and coalesce to use the staging values when there is a match, and distinct to remove the duplicates that then introduces for your second staging value:

```
select distinct pt.assignment_id,
  coalesce(st.effective_start_date, pt.effective_start_date) as effective_start_date,
  coalesce(st.effective_end_date, pt.effective_end_date) as effective_end_date,
  coalesce(st.action_reason, pt.action_reason) as action_reason
from prod_table pt
left join staging_table st
on st.assignment_id = pt.assignment_id
and (st.effective_start_date = pt.effective_start_date
  or st.effective_end_date = pt.effective_end_date)
order by assignment_id, effective_start_date
```

| ASSIGNMENT_ID | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | ACTION_REASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30001 | 2010-01-01 | 2015-02-02 | Name Change |
| 30001 | 2015-02-03 | 2021-05-05 | Dept Change |
| 30001 | 2021-05-06 | 4712-12-31 | Manager Change |

If you want to update the data in your main table then you can use merge with much the same logic, and a `delete where` clause to remove the now-duplicates:

```
merge into prod_table pt
using staging_table st
on (
  st.assignment_id = pt.assignment_id
  and (st.effective_start_date = pt.effective_start_date
    or st.effective_end_date = pt.effective_end_date)
)
when matched then update set
  pt.effective_end_date = st.effective_end_date,
  pt.action_reason = st.action_reason
delete where pt.effective_start_date != st.effective_start_date
```

That updates all the matching rows but only the end-date and reason, leaving the original start dates; and then deletes those matched rows which don't match the staging start date, leaving just one.

```
select * from prod_table
```

| ASSIGNMENT_ID | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | ACTION_REASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30001 | 2010-01-01 | 2015-02-02 | Name Change |
| 30001 | 2015-02-03 | 2021-05-05 | Dept Change |
| 30001 | 2021-05-06 | 4712-12-31 | Manager Change |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KyB9YpgF)

But if you have staging data that doesn't exactly match existing dates then it's going to potentially get a lot more complicated; if that is the case then you'll need to ask a new question clearly setting out all of the scenarios you will need to handle (gaps, overlaps, clashes, ...) and the behaviour you expect for each one.

Comment: Hi Alex Poole, THANK YOU VERY MUCH for helping me on this. APPRECIATE you MAN. I will use the SQL statement in reporting. I don't have inser,update,delete privileges to TABLES. :(

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure - "will be removed" was ambiguous, and staging tables are usually used for updating other data. I'll leave the merge there for reference.

Comment: thank you boss Alex Poole! I know this is a very hard question :(

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not quite sure about what exactly you are trying to get (what are the conditions) it looks to me like something that could be done using [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) which alows you to manage your data pretty much like wokring with excel sheet.
The code below doesn't do the job but shows you some of the ways to condition and manipulate your data:
Sample data:

```sql
--  stg table
        ID EFF_START EFF_END   REASON            
---------- --------- --------- ------------------
     30001 06-MAY-21 31-DEC-12 Manager Change    -- end year 4712
     
-- prod table
        ID EFF_START EFF_END   REASON                                                                                             
---------- --------- --------- ------------------
     30001 01-JAN-10 02-FEB-15 Name Change       
     30001 03-FEB-15 05-MAY-21 Name Change       
     30001 06-MAY-21 03-MAR-23 Name Change       
     30001 04-MAR-23 31-DEC-12 Name Change      -- end year 4712
```

Main SQL:

```sql
Select   ID, S_EFF_START, S_EFF_END, S_REASON, RN, EFF_START, EFF_END, DATSTAT, REASON, RSNSTAT
From
    ( Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By p.ID Order By p.ID, p.EFF_START) "RN",
              p.ID "ID", p.EFF_START "EFF_START", p.EFF_END "EFF_END", p.REASON "REASON",
              s.EFF_START "S_EFF_START", s.EFF_END "S_EFF_END", s.REASON "S_REASON"
      From stg s
      Left Join prod p ON( 1 = 1 ) 
    )
    MODEL Partition By (ID)
          Dimension By (RN, S_EFF_START, S_EFF_END)
          Measures (EFF_START, EFF_END, REASON, S_REASON, Cast('' As VarChar2(64)) "DATSTAT", Cast('' As VarChar2(64)) "RSNSTAT")
    Rules (
              EFF_START[ANY, ANY, ANY] =  CASE  WHEN  EFF_START[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) 
                                                THEN  CV(S_EFF_START) 
                                          ELSE EFF_START[CV(), CV(), CV()]
                                          END,
              EFF_END[ANY, ANY, ANY]   =  CASE  WHEN  EFF_END[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) 
                                                THEN  CV(S_EFF_END) 
                                          ELSE  EFF_END[CV(), CV(), CV()]
                                          END,
              REASON[ANY, ANY, ANY]    =  CASE  WHEN  EFF_START[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) And 
                                                      EFF_END[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) 
                                                THEN  S_REASON[CV(), CV(), CV()] 
                                          ELSE  REASON[CV(), CV(), CV()]
                                          END,
              --
              DATSTAT[ANY, ANY, ANY]   =  CASE  WHEN   EFF_START[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) OR
                                                      EFF_END[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) 
                                                THEN  'Date(s) changed to one(s) from stg table' 
                                          ELSE 'No change'
                                          END,
              RSNSTAT[ANY, ANY, ANY]  =  CASE  WHEN   EFF_START[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) OR
                                                      EFF_END[CV(), CV(), CV()] Between CV(S_EFF_START) And CV(S_EFF_END) 
                                                THEN  'REASON changed' 
                                          ELSE 'No change'
                                          END
          )
```

Result:

```sql
--  
--      R e s u l t : 
        ID S_EFF_START S_EFF_END S_REASON                       RN EFF_START EFF_END   DATSTAT                                     REASON                 RSNSTAT                
---------- ----------- --------- ---------------------- ---------- --------- --------- ------------------------------------------- ---------------------- -----------------------
     30001 06-MAY-21   31-DEC-12 Manager Change                  1 01-JAN-10 02-FEB-15 No change                                   Name Change            No change              
     30001 06-MAY-21   31-DEC-12 Manager Change                  2 03-FEB-15 05-MAY-21 No change                                   Name Change            No change              
     30001 06-MAY-21   31-DEC-12 Manager Change                  3 06-MAY-21 31-DEC-12 Date(s) changed to one(s) from stg table    Manager Change         REASON changed         
     30001 06-MAY-21   31-DEC-12 Manager Change                  4 06-MAY-21 31-DEC-12 Date(s) changed to one(s) from stg table    Manager Change         REASON changed
```

It looks a bit complicated but it is reliable and fast. If you can take a look at the docs - it will come handy sooner or later.

Comment: Man! my nose is bleeding right now just by looking at your SQL statement.

Comment: @IMDUMB It is not as complicated as it looks, believe me. On the other hand - it saved my ass several times primarily for it is so fast that I thought something is wrong with my database. Well, it wasn't. This thingy is just fast and dear God knows why - I certainly don't.